# Flow control of processing ajax requests (i.e. only processing the next request after the previous request has completed)

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angular-promise

I have written the following code but I'm have a problem with assigning `$scope.sessionKey = data.result;` before it gets passed in the next ajax call `result.params.sSessionKey = $scope.sessionKey` (and yes `result.name=='get_session_key'` evaluates for the first iteration of the loop). As you can see I've tried having a go with `$q` but all the tutorials on promises and defers just don't make any sense to me (even stuff like [this](https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2014/02/04/angularjspart-11-promises/) doesn't help me).

Can you please show me how to loop over the `angular.forEach(...` and only execute the next test when the previous one has completed.

```
// Angular's implementation of JSON-RPC (as seen here > http://jsfiddle.net/89D4b/1/)
angular.module("JSON-RPC",[]).config([...]);

// Angular
var app = angular.module('testsApp', ['JSON-RPC']);
app.controller('testsCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q) {

    // populates the table on startup
    $http.get("functions_as_JSON.php")
    .success(function(response) {
        // store the data locally for angular to loop through
        $scope.data = response;

        // create a promise for the sessionKey
        var defer = $q.defer();
        var promise = defer.promise;
        promise.then(function(data){
            $scope.sessionKey = data.result;
        });

        //////////  AUTO RUN THE TESTS  //////////

        angular.forEach($scope.data.results,function(value,index){
            $scope.runTest(value);
        });
    });

    // test function
    $scope.runTest = function(result) {
        // (on all but the first test ...)
        // if the sessionKey is in the JSON put it in the params to send with the JSON-RPC
        if(result.params.sSessionKey) { result.params.sSessionKey = $scope.sessionKey; }
        // test the method
        $http.jsonrpc($scope.data.endPoint, result.method, result.params)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // if there are no errors
            if (data.error === null && !data.result.status) {
                // on the first test the sessionKey gets stored
                if(result.name=='get_session_key') {
                    $scope.sessionKey = data.result;
                    //defer.resolve(data);
                    //$scope.$evalAsync(function($scope) { $scope.sessionKey = data.result; });
                }
                $scope.testSuccess(result, data, status, headers, config);
            } else {
                $scope.testFailed(result, data, status, headers, config);
            }
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config){ $scope.testFailed(result, data, status, headers, config); });
    }

    $scope.testSuccess = function(result, data, status, headers, config) {
        result.response = {'status':status, 'post':result.params, 'data':JSON.stringify(data)};
        result.status_class = 'positive';
        result.status = 'success';
    }

    $scope.testFailed = function(result, data, status, headers, config) {
        result.response = {'status':status, 'post':result.params, 'data':JSON.stringify(data)};
        result.status_class = 'negative';
        result.status = 'failed';
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

I have modified it to the following but still to no avail

```
// Angular's implementation of JSON-RPC (as seen here > http://jsfiddle.net/89D4b/1/)
angular.module("JSON-RPC",[]).config([...]);

// Angular
var app = angular.module('testsApp', ['JSON-RPC']);
app.controller('testsCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q, $timeout) {

    // populates the table on startup
    $http.get("limesurvey_api_functions_as_JSON.php")
    .success(function(response) {
        // store the data locally for angular to loop through
        $scope.data = response;

        //////////  AUTO RUN THE TESTS  //////////

        var promiseArray = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.data.results,function(value,index){
            promiseArray.push($scope.runTest(value));
        });
        $q.all(promiseArray).then(function(){
            console.log("Angular is fun !!");
        });
    });

    // test function
    $scope.runTest = function(result){
        return { then: function(Resolve,Reject){
            // if the sessionKey has been set put it in the params
            if(result.params.sSessionKey) { result.params.sSessionKey = $scope.sessionKey; console.log($scope.sessionKey); }
            // test the method
            $http.jsonrpc($scope.data.endPoint, result.method, result.params)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // if there are no errors
                if (data.error === null && !data.result.status) {
                    // if it's the first test store the sessionKey
                    if(result.method=='get_session_key') {
                        $scope.sessionKey = data.result;
                        if ($scope.sessionKey == data.result) { Resolve(); }
                    } else {
                        Resolve();
                    }
                    $scope.testSuccess(result, data, status, headers, config);
                } else {
                    Reject();
                    $scope.testFailed(result, data, status, headers, config);
                }
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                Reject();
                $scope.testFailed(result, data, status, headers, config);
            });
        }}
    }

    $scope.testSuccess = function(result, data, status, headers, config) {
        ...
    }

    $scope.testFailed = function(result, data, status, headers, config) {
        ...
    }
});
```

**EDIT 2**

And this :(

```
//////////  AUTO RUN THE TESTS  //////////

angular.forEach($scope.data.results,function(value,index){
    $scope.runTest(value).then(function(data) {
        if(result.method=='get_session_key') {
            // if it's the first test store the sessionKey
            $scope.sessionKey = data.result;
        }
    });
});

...

// test function
$scope.runTest = function(result){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    // if the sessionKey has been set put it in the params
    if(result.params.sSessionKey) { result.params.sSessionKey = $scope.sessionKey; console.log($scope.sessionKey); }
    // test the method
    $http.jsonrpc($scope.data.endPoint, result.method, result.params)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // if there are no errors
        if (data.error === null && !data.result.status) {
            $scope.testSuccess(result, data, status, headers, config);
            deferred.resolve(data);
        } else {
            $scope.testFailed(result, data, status, headers, config);
            deferred.reject(data);
        }
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        $scope.testFailed(result, data, status, headers, config);
        deferred.reject(data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right I finally got this running with:

```
// populates the table on startup
$http.get("functions_as_JSON.php")
.success(function(response) {
    // store the data locally for angular to loop through
    $scope.data = response;

    //////////  AUTO RUN THE TESTS  //////////

    var currentFunctionIndex = 0;
    function nextTest() {
        if (currentFunctionIndex < $scope.data.results.length) {
            $scope.runTest($scope.data.results[currentFunctionIndex++]).then(nextTest);
        }
    }
    nextTest();
});

...

// test function
$scope.runTest = function(result){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    // if the sessionKey has been set put it in the params
    if(result.params.sSessionKey) { result.params.sSessionKey = $scope.sessionKey; }
    // test the method
    $http.jsonrpc($scope.data.endPoint, result.method, result.params)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // if there are no errors
        if (data.error === null && !data.result.status) {
            // if it's the first test store the sessionKey
            if(result.method=='get_session_key') {
                $scope.sessionKey = data.result;
            }
            $scope.testSuccess(result, data, status, headers, config);
            deferred.resolve();
        } else {
            $scope.testFailed(result, data, status, headers, config);
            deferred.reject();
        }
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        $scope.testFailed(result, data, status, headers, config);
        deferred.reject();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I kind of understand why this works but in my mind a lot more could be done in the documentation to explain this (especially when looping through data)

Answer (score 1):

This is not as hard as you are making it.

Editing based on your comments:

```
$http.get("functions_as_JSON.php")
.success(function(response) {
    $scope.data = response;
    $scope.sessionKey = data.result;
    var promiseArray = [];

    angular.forEach($scope.data.results,function(value,index){
        promiseArray.push($scope.runTestPromise(value));
    });
    $q.all(promises).then(function(){
        alert("Angular is fun !!");
    });
});

$scope.runTestPromise = function(data){
     return { then: function(Resolve,Reject){
     if (data == "valid data"){
         Resolve("valid data");
     } else {
         Reject("invalid data");
     }
}
```

I didn't run the code but this is the drill, you wrap your test in a promise and then you let $q resolve them one after another.

Comment: I'm not to sure what you saying. `$scope.sessionKey = data.result;` has to be assigned in the first runTest to be used in the second runTest. Also `$scope.runTest = {then: function(onResolve,onReject){` is not a function call (I think). Any chance you can put this in a completed example

Comment: Hopefully this is easier to understand now. This is just the way to chain promises in $q, I didn't look that much into your code.

Comment: (BTW `$scope.sessionKey = data.result` is based on the successful return of `data.result` in the first loop of `angular.forEach(...`)